# Can't access database server with remote connection

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm a beginner and I'm trying to connect remotely to my MySQL database server, but still don't succeed.

I have a dedicated server and my provider doesn't want to help me.
-`CentOS 6` with Parallels `Plesk 12 (64-bit)`-

I'm accessing my server trough Parallels Plesk. I set up a administrator and database user with "allow remote connection from any host".

I'm able to access my server with `FTP` and the `MySQL` database server locally, but not from my computer.

I have this error displaying when trying to connect with php:

`Warning: PDO::__construct(): MySQL server has gone away in /Users/X/Sites/connexionBDD.php on line 31`

Here is the way I connect:

```
define("DB_SERVER","mywebsite.com:8443");
define("DB_NAME","databasName");
define("DB_USER","MyUser");
define("DB_PWD","MyPassword");


try {
//line 31
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_SERVER.';dbname='.DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PWD);
}
catch (Exception $e) {
  die($e->getMessage());
}
echo 'You made it';
```

For `DB_SERVER`, if using `IP` address, do I need to give `V4 + port`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The host and port should not be specified in the same variable, split them up and define your DSN like below. Additionally, check the port is the correct one, MySQL by default uses port 3306.

```
define("DB_SERVER","mywebsite.com");
define("DB_PORT","8443");
define("DB_NAME","databasName");
define("DB_USER","MyUser");
define("DB_PWD","MyPassword");

try {
//line 31
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_SERVER.';port='.DB_PORT.';dbname='.DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PWD);
}
catch (Exception $e) {
  die($e->getMessage());
}
echo 'You made it';
```

Comment: should I give www.mywebsite.com OR IPv6?

Comment: Doesn't really matter if DNS resolves to the same IP address.

Comment: I still have the same error displaying + this one: `Warning: PDO::__construct(): Error while reading greeting packet. PID=598 in /Users/x/Sites/connexionBDD.php on line 31
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away`

Comment: is it fine to trying to access it on my localhost computer? `http://localhost/~x/connexionBDD.php`

Comment: Are you sure the port is 8443? The standard port for MySQL is 3306.

Comment: I think you are right, I saw this port for my server and not for the MySQL server. Now I get `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused`.  
Even if this user has remote access.  
Is there a way to explain me this trough SSH commands?

Comment: Perhaps a firewall issue?

Comment: Yes, when I'm accessing Parallels trough: `https://IPv6:port` chrome tells me `your connection is not private`. I have to click on `more` then he tells me several things `your server created his own security certificate, wich chrome can not trust...`. Clicking on continue takes me to my panel

Comment: It was a Firewall issue! Thank's a lot for your help!!